# SQL Server find records that have the same data and keep one

Tags: sql-server, query, table

I have a table containing Services (**service_id**) for different Packages(**package_id**)

I am trying to find Packages with the exact same Services and keep only one Package of them

```
dummy_id    package_id  service_id
    4           4           3
    5           4           4
    6           4           5
    7           5           3
    8           5           4
    9           5           5
    10          6           3
    12          6           5
    13          7           3
    14          7           4
    15          7           5
    16          8           3
    17          8           4
    18          8           5
    19          9           3
    20          9           4
    21          9           5
    22          9           6
    23          9           7
    24          9           8
    25          10          3
    26          10          4
    27          10          5
```

I have an SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a07d1/3/23

In the example, **PackageIDs 6 and 9** do not have the same Services. The other Packages have the same Services so one is kept (**PackageID 4**)

```
dummy_id    package_id  service_id
    4           4           3
    5           4           4
    6           4           5
    10          6           3
    12          6           5
    19          9           3
    20          9           4
    21          9           5
    22          9           6
    23          9           7
    24          9           8
```

Thank you

Comment: The problem is how do you define th *the same Services*, why is it `3,4,5` and not `3,4` , or `5` , or.... etc ? If the *the same Services* pattern is known it's much easier , a simple having count would do the trick

Comment: Hi Ergest. Package_ids that have the very same Services_ids must left to only one. PackageID 9 has more Services although it includes the Services of PackageID 4. It is different. PackageID 6 is missing ServiceID 4 so it is different. PackageIDs 4,5,7,8,10 has the very same ServiceIDs.

Comment: I'm assuming the `service_id` is unique within each `package_id`? (I.e. the same `service_id` can't exist multiple times for the same `package_id`.)

Comment: Hi J.D. Yeap. That is correct. We cannot have the same Service more than once inside a Package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the following steps can be found in this [working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Deh9O4mI)

First we find the package_id with same values
with the following query,

```
select  package_id,
        rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
from dbo.package_components 
group by  package_id;
```

Then we find the min package_id for the most repeated same values and the remaining package_id (which in your case have the different values),

```
select min(package_id) as min_package_id ,
       count(rnk) as rnk
from (  select  package_id,
                rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
        from dbo.package_components 
        group by  package_id
      ) tbl 
group by rnk
```

In the end we use above query as a subquery with the main table and will get the desired result:

```
select pc.dummy_id,
       pc.package_id,
       pc.service_id
from dbo.package_components  pc
inner join (select min(package_id) as min_package_id ,
                  count(rnk) as rnk
            from (  select  package_id,
                            rank() over (order by count(*)) as rnk
                    from dbo.package_components 
                    group by  package_id
                 ) tbl 
           group by rnk  
          ) as x on x.min_package_id=pc.package_id
order by pc.dummy_id asc;
```

Maybe not the best solution but I guess will give the desired result.